# Unique index to guarantee uniqueness within a number of consecutive days

Tags: database, unique-constraint

I want to send out friendly reminder emails to our users. For example when a user hasn't been logged in for 30 consecutive days (there are multiple different cases when we send an email).

Every night I will check for the different conditions and send out e-mails and I will create a database entry for every email sent. Now here's the twist: I want to **guarantee** that a single user does not get more than one e-mail in **7 consecutive days**.

Is there a clever, general purpose way of solving this? Basically I need to transform the current datetime in a way, that a combination of the transformed datetime and the userid will be unique for the next 7 days (or in general, for a given timespan).

The "closest" I can think of is using the current week of the year. But this has two issue: It's a special case (only works because of the special case of 7 days) and more important this will only guarantee a single email per week, but not consecutive days. E.g. the user gets an email on saturday and another one on monday.

Note: Please don't suggest solutions which rely on enforcing this constraint on application level (like comparing the current datetime with the latest from the database). I want a clean solution which guarantees uniqueness on the database level.

Edit: I didn't mention the database system I am using because it should be a general purpose solution which solely depends on support unique indexes. I cannot use things like triggers.

### Ideas so far

Here's what I came up with since I posted the questions. I'm not happy with them.

1. When sending out an e-mail, make a bulk insert of seven datasets. If it fails, don't send out the email. This requires a index on (user, day). The inserted records will basically block any attempts within the next seven days.
2. Without unique index. We need one entry per user. We update the entry before sending the email. Pseudo SQL `UPDATE email_lock WHERE user=[user] and last_send + 7 DAY < NOW() SET last_send = NOW()`. If the number of updated records is `0`, don't send the email. This will work and is atomic.

Comment: You can divide the number of days passed since Jan 1, 1900 by 7 and truncate the result but your second issue remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
select user_id, MAX(send_date) as last_send_date from emails 
group by user_id
having MAX(send_date) < NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days';
```

It returns you the users you can send an email to.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d2a51/3

Comment: This doesn't guarantee any uniqueness. Two concurrent clients will both get the same list of users which will result in two emails.

Comment: Such an enforcement on the database level should be done with triggers. I don't think you can make such constraint. For example, in Oracle CHECK constraint has several restrictions, for example it cannot refer to SYSDATE nor it can contain subqueries: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_constraints.htm#ADFNS00606

I'm afraid you'll have to do this either with trigger or move this logic to the application. Transaction isolation does the job.

Comment: I already added two working solutions two my question (especially the second one). Just looking for the most elegant.

Comment: This second solution MAY be working - it depends on the way you manage transactions and what transaction isolation level you use. If two concurrent threads begin transaction, they both have a snapshot of the data in the table and they both may have update row count > 0... What can solve this problem would be either acquiring explicitly an exclusive lock on the table, using serializable transaction isolation level, or having one thread to collect users to send an email and then run multiple threads sending them.